# Dot product for orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I want ask which must be the dot product for vectors (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1), so they can form a orthonormalbasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the $i$th such vector $v_i$. Let $V$ denote the matrix satisfying $V_{ik}=(v_i)_k$. We seek an inner product $a,\,b\mapsto a_kM_{kl}b_l$, with implicit summation over repeated indices, so that $\delta_{ij}=V_{ik}M_{kl}V_{jl}$ i.e. $VMV^T=I$. So take $M=V^{-1}(V^T)^{-1}=(V^TV)^{-1}$. In this case $$V=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right),\,V^{T}V=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right),\,M=\frac{1}{4}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 3
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: thank you, but i have to get a formula for dot product in this case..

Comment: @melanzana You mean $(3(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3)-a_1b_2-a_2b_1-a_1b_3-a_3b_1-a_2b_3-a_3b_2)/4$?

Comment: yes, thank you very much!!!